# How to add a common paragraph in Short description of product . Magento 1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.4

I have many product in my website . And for all this product i want to write "please contact : xxx-xxx-xx" after the short description . I want to know in which php file i need to edi for to add this common paragraph in my product description .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in the `product listing` page then you will have to navigate to :

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/package/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

In this file look for this line:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
```

If you want to add it to the `product details` page then you should navigate to:

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/package/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and add your sentence below this line:

```
<div class="short-description">
<div class="std">
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
</div>
```